# Transverse intersection and conditions on Tor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, derived-functors

Consider $X$ and $Y$ varieties inside a smooth variety $M$.
I say that $X$ and $Y$ intersect transversally at $m\in M$ if the tangent spaces of $X$ and $Y$ span the whole tangent space of $M$ at $m$.
I see, for example just from Serre's Tor-formula, that intersection theory often deals with $\operatorname{Tor}$, but I cannot see the link between the definition of transversal intersection and it.
Some question I have: has transversal intersection something to do with the condition $\operatorname{Tor}_{>0}(\mathcal{O}_{X,m},\mathcal{O}_{Y,m})=0$? Both are "good intersection conditions" but does one implies the other?

Feel free to consider intersection of Cohen-Macaulay varieties, even to take $X$ hypersurface. I'm trying to have an insight.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $X$ is a locally complete intersection and $Y$ is Cohen--Macaulay. Then loally $\mathcal{O}_X$ has a free resolution given by the Koszul complex. Then $Tor$'s are computed by the restriction of this resolution to $Y$. If the dimension of the intersection is the expected one (this is a weaker condition than the condition about the tangent spaces) then this restriction is exact (by the CM property), hence $Tor$ vanish.

Comment: Ok! I was thinking about tangent spaces because I was trying to understand smoothness of the intersection. Something along the line "when $\operatorname{Tor}$ vanish at $m$ I should have $X$ and $Y$ smooth at $m$ to obtain a smooth intersection". Something similar happens in the paper I was reading, and the intersection has indeed expected dimension!

Comment: Smoothness has nothing to do with vanishing of $Tor$'s --- the expected dimension is the appropriate condition (under appropriate lci and CM assumptions).